# Java printing html as pdf

Tags: java, pdf

i have installed doPDF printer driver, and i want to use it from Java to convert HTML to PDF.

```
PrintService service = getPrinterByName("doPDF");                
DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
Doc document = new SimpleDoc(conn.getInputStream(), DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
File f = new File(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")),"out.pdf");

attr.add(new Destination(f.toURI()));
printJob.print(document, attr);
```

The problem is that when i open out.pdf with any pdf reader it says format error and with notepad++ it shows just html.

```
    private PrintService getPrinterByName(String name) {
    PrintService[] list = getPrintersList();
    if (list.length > 0) {
        for (PrintService service : list) {
            if (service.getName().contains(name)) {
                return service;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private PrintService[] getPrintersList() {
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, null);

    return services;
}
```

Comment: Please post the source of `getPrinterByName()`

Answer (score 0):

I needed this operation silent, and the only way was using OpenOffice API. Any other method requires user input/confirmation.

I used [JOD Converter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to achieve this. And a little bit more, I convert any file to PDF (i.e.: any Microsoft Office document, any image, any Open Office document, text, html) and then merge everything to one PDF, with header and footer, including page count, date, user and such. This works both in windows or linux.

Just in case you don't need silent:

```
    public void print() {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {
            desktop.print(new File("web.html"));
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

User is prompted to select printer, go for PDFCreator or doPDF.

Hope it helps!